# Using the Eclipse Collections library, how do I sort MutableMap on the value?

Tags: eclipse-collections

Suppose I have `MutableMap<String, Integer>`, and I want to sort on the `Integer` value.

What would be the recommended way to do that with this library? Is there a utility or method or recommended way of going about this with the Eclipse Collections library?

For example, suppose:

```
MutableMap<String, Integer> mutableMap = Maps.mutable.empty();

mutableMap.add(Tuples.pair("Three", 3));
mutableMap.add(Tuples.pair("One", 1));
mutableMap.add(Tuples.pair("Two", 2));
```

And I'd like to end up with a `MutableMap<String, Integer>` containing the same elements, but ordered/sorted so that the first element is ("One", 1), the second element ("Two", 2), and the third element ("Three", 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no direct API available in Eclipse Collections to sort a `Map` based on its values.

One alternative would be to flip the map into a `MutableSortedMap` using [`flipUniqueValues`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/map/MutableMap.html#flipUniqueValues--).

```
MutableSortedMap<Integer, String> sortedMap = SortedMaps.mutable.empty();
sortedMap.putAll(mutableMap.flipUniqueValues());

System.out.println(sortedMap);
```

This will give you a `MutableSortedMap` that is sorted on the `Integer` keys. The output here will be: `{1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three}`

You could also store the `Pairs` in a `List` first and then group them uniquely using the `String` key to create the `MutableMap`. If the values in the `Map` are the `Pair` instances, they can be used to create a sorted `List`, `SortedSet` or `SortedBag` using direct APIs.

```
MutableList<Pair<String, Integer>> list = Lists.mutable.with(
        Tuples.pair("Three", 3),
        Tuples.pair("One", 1),
        Tuples.pair("Two", 2)
);
MutableMap<String, Pair<String, Integer>> map =
        list.groupByUniqueKey(Pair::getOne);

System.out.println(map);

MutableList<Pair<String, Integer>> sortedList =
        map.toSortedListBy(Pair::getTwo);

MutableSortedSet<Pair<String, Integer>> sortedSet =
        map.toSortedSetBy(Pair::getTwo);

MutableSortedBag<Pair<String, Integer>> sortedBag =
        map.toSortedBagBy(Pair::getTwo);

System.out.println(sortedList);
System.out.println(sortedSet);
System.out.println(sortedBag);
```

Outputs:

```
{One=One:1, Three=Three:3, Two=Two:2}
[One:1, Two:2, Three:3]
[One:1, Two:2, Three:3]
[One:1, Two:2, Three:3]
```

All of the `toSorted` methods above operate on the values only. This is why I stored the values as the `Pair` instances.

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).